# SyntaxError exception in React Native Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I can't get Firebase realtime database data, getting exception and can't understand why.

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at App.componentDidMount (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:1571:45)
at App.proxiedComponentDidMount (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:57980:42)
at commitLifeCycles (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:31136:28)
at commitLayoutEffects (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:33340:13)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackImpl (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:20647:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:20743:37)
at commitRootImpl (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:33172:15)
at unstable_runWithPriority (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:55717:18)
at runWithPriority (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:24203:16)
at commitRoot (blob:http://localhost:8081/debac782-dd29-4750-a1b8-dc8e57c59632:33041:9)"
```

In the App.js constructor I initialize firebase like this (works fine):

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

And in componentDidMount() I am trying to get the database ref:

```
    componentDidMount() {            
        firebase.database().ref('listings').once("value", snapshot => {
          //handle snapshot data
        });         
   }
```

Comment: Did you activate the database from console?

Comment: No, why? The instruction says nothing about that https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

Comment: I am sure but i think ref('lintings').once.....i think mistake is once....instend of once ,there should be on

Comment: .on() is for continuous polling, .once() is for a single read. The error is the same.

Comment: @DmitriBorohhov I've added my answer. I think you need to make change to reference call. Take care of the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the remote debugger for React Native is causing syntax errors in bundling. Once I disable remote debugging, the issue disappears and I can get the data from Firebase database.

This looks to be the same as described in the [Github issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2010).

Answer (score 0):

Take care of the syntax:

```
firebase.database().ref('listings').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  // handle snapshot data
});
```

.once() returns a `Promise<DataSnapshot>` hence, you need to handle it with .then()

> once
>
> `once(eventType: EventType, successCallback?: function, failureCallbackOrContext?: function | Object | null, context?: Object | null): Promise<DataSnapshot>`

From  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once

Comment: Tried your suggestion, didn't work. The syntax is just a lambda expression, which worked fine on a React web project, so I wonder why it doesn't work in a clean React Native project. The second argument of the .once() function is a successCallback, which returns a DataSnapshot when ready.

Comment: Yes, I did. No change.